# How to get response times from Axios

Tags: axios

Can anyone suggest any ways to get response times from Axios?  I've found axios-timing but I don't really like it (controversial, I know).  I'm just wondering if anyone else has found some good ways to log response times.

Comment: What about Network tab on dev tools?

Comment: It's as part of automated tests, so needs to be in code...

Comment: Another Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61712051/4050261

Answer (score 66):

You can use the interceptor concept of axios.

Request interceptor will set startTime

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
 
  config.metadata = { startTime: new Date()}
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Response interceptor will set endTime & calculate the duration

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
 
  response.config.metadata.endTime = new Date()
  response.duration = response.config.metadata.endTime - response.config.metadata.startTime
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  error.config.metadata.endTime = new Date();
  error.duration = error.config.metadata.endTime - error.config.metadata.startTime;
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: Are we allowed to add random stuff to config?

Comment: I think, you have bug. When you try to get arrays of urls time add to previews and dont reset. SO last response calculate from first response time

Comment: If you mis-configure axios, you get an error but it doesn't have `error.config` so the error side of this need to check `if (error.config) {` before setting the endTime or duration.

Comment: I'm seeing an error: `Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'AxiosRequestConfig'.`

Comment: If you get an error "Property 'metadata' does not exist on type ..." that means you're using Typescript and `metadata` really doesn't exist for interface `AxiosRequestConfig`. You can define a new interface that will extend `AxiosRequestConfig` and cast config to it like `(config as YourInterfaceWithMeta).metadata`

Comment: @patrick-fitzgerald, Are you setting the 'config.metadata' first?

Comment: @patrick-fitzgerald. One more solution in Typescript. instead of `config.metadata` you can use `config.data.metadata`. in this case you don't need to define new interface as @DarkZ suggested, because `data: any`

Comment: You can also `return { ...config, metadata: {startTime: new Date() }}` using ts without issues. Incoming config can be typed as `(config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) =>`

Answer (score 24):

This is my solution, by setting the header in the interceptor:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const url = 'https://example.com'

const instance = axios.create()

instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers['request-startTime'] = process.hrtime()
    return config
})

instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    const start = response.config.headers['request-startTime']
    const end = process.hrtime(start)
    const milliseconds = Math.round((end[0] * 1000) + (end[1] / 1000000))
    response.headers['request-duration'] = milliseconds
    return response
})

instance.get(url).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.headers['request-duration'])
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(`Error`)
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's another way to do it:

```
const instance = axios.create() 

instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.headers['request-startTime'] = new Date().getTime();
  return config
})

instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  const currentTime = new Date().getTime()      
  const startTime = response.config.headers['request-startTime']      
  response.headers['request-duration'] = currentTime - startTime      
  return response
})

instance.get('https://example.com')
  .then((response) => {      
    console.log(response.headers['request-duration'])
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(`Error`)
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

easy way do this with async \ await, but not ideal :

```
const start = Date.now()
await axios.get(url)
const finish = Date.now()

const time = (finish - start) / 1000
```

This would be time about of axios call. Not so ideal, but showing and easy to implement

Answer (score 3):

piggybacking off of [@user3653268](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3653268/user3653268)- I modified their answer to use with react hooks and display x.xxx seconds using a modulo.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Main() {
  const [axiosTimer, setAxiosTimer] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = () => {
      let startTime = Date.now();
      axios.post('urlstuff')
      .then(response => {
          console.log('handleSubmit response: ', response);
          axiosTimerFunc(startTime);
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log("handleSubmit error:", err.response.data.message)
          axiosTimerFunc(startTime);
          setLoading(false);
      });
    }

  const axiosTimerFunc = (startTime) => {
    let now = Date.now();
    let seconds = Math.floor((now - startTime)/1000);
    let milliseconds = Math.floor((now - startTime)%1000);
    setAxiosTimer(`${seconds}.${milliseconds} seconds`);
  }

  return(
     <div>
        <h2>Load Time: {axiosTimer}</h2>
     </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way to do it :

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    console.timeEnd(response.config.url);
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    console.timeEnd(error.response.config.url); 
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

axios.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    console.time(config.url );
    return config;
}, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: Until you have two simultaneous requests for the same URL (possibly even different HTTP methods).

Answer (score 0):

Its way long after but this is my simple workaround

```
function performSearch() {
        var start = Date.now();
        var url='http://example.com';
        var query='hello';
        axios.post(url,{'par1':query})
            .then(function (res) {
                var millis = Date.now() - start;
                $('.timer').html(""+Math.floor(millis/1000)+"s")
            })
            .catch(function (res) {
                console.log(res)
            })


    }
```

this is my workaround

Comment: This looks like you'd have to do it for every request. Wouldn't interceptors be a more central and elegant way to capture this?

Comment: I did it like this, but getting negative times ;)

Answer (score -1):

actually you can get it through the "x-response-time" header that you get from the response on the axios request

```
axios({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'something.com',

        })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.headers['x-response-time']);
          })
```

Comment: i'm not seeing this, although it could have been added in a later release. are you sure it's not a server header?

Comment: I also don't have this, and I'm on the newest axios version.

Comment: I think this is only possible if the server itself returns that header. Please correct me.