# How to get response time of api request in react native?

Tags: react-native

> I want to get time difference between a request & response. For example in below code what is time interval to complete the request ?

```
return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
   **# How much time above fetch request took ?**
  return responseJson.movies;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take current time using Date

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
```

before api call and after your response.
and subtract both time.

You will get answer in miliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You Just need to set a variable with time before initiating the call and get the difference from current time inside the response method.

Lets say that this is your function

```
function getData()
{
 const start = new Date();
 return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
   const timeTaken= (new Date())-start;
  return responseJson.movies;
})

}
```

timeTaken will be the actual time taken for the request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that, we can calculate time difference like you suggested. As we are dealing with javascript so its not accurate time calculation. I need some in-build solution like. response.status give us code 200 for success. Is there any method to get time like response.turnAroundTime etc.?

Comment: If you can use something like axios you have more options
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874594/how-to-get-response-times-from-axios

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

To Measure the Starting Time when API called;

```
const start = new Date();
console.log(start, 'start time in page');
```

To Measure the Ending Time and Time Taken Between start and end  when API is called to response end;

```
const timeTaken = (new Date()) - start;
const timeTakenSec = timeTaken / 1000;
console.log(timeTakenSec, 'time taken in  page');
```

**Example :**

```
   //To Measure Starting Time before api call

    const start = new Date();
    console.log(start, 'start time in page');
    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Network response was not ok (Status: ${response.status})`);
          }
          // Parse the response body as JSON
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          // Data contains the parsed JSON response from the API
          return data;

    //To Measure the End Time after response data

    const timeTaken = (new Date()) - start;
    const timeTakenSec = timeTaken / 1000;
    console.log(timeTakenSec, 'time taken in  page');
        })
```