# How to measure how much time request take in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, python-requests, axios

```
const axios = require("axios");

axios.get('url')
  .then(response => {
     console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

How can i measure how much time did it take for website to return full page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`performance.now()`](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_now) to measure the time between starting and finishing the request.

```
const axios = require("axios");
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');

let time = performance.now();

axios.get('url')
  .then(response => {
     console.log(response)
     console.log(`${(performance.now() - time) / 1000} seconds`);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, You can easily use `axios.interceptors` for getting the time at request start and after the response has reached And add it as a part of `axios.create`.
For request:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  config.timeData = { startTime: new Date()}
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

And for response:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  response.config.timeData.endTime = new Date()
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

You can checkout more on interceptors [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 (and beyond), a better way is to use the built-in `fetch` API which automatically captures request timing measurements. Here's an example:

```js
import { performance } from 'node:perf_hooks';

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
const response = await fetch(url);
await response.json();
console.log(performance.getEntriesByName(url));
```

Outputs:

```js
[
  PerformanceResourceTiming {
    name: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    entryType: 'resource',
    startTime: 31.364732027053833,
    duration: 764.867231965065,
    initiatorType: 'fetch',
    nextHopProtocol: undefined,
    workerStart: 0,
    redirectStart: 0,
    redirectEnd: 0,
    fetchStart: 31.364732027053833,
    domainLookupStart: undefined,
    domainLookupEnd: undefined,
    connectStart: undefined,
    connectEnd: undefined,
    secureConnectionStart: undefined,
    requestStart: 0,
    responseStart: 0,
    responseEnd: 796.2319639921188,
    transferSize: 300,
    encodedBodySize: 0,
    decodedBodySize: 0
  }
]
```

The `duration` property provides what you're looking for. See https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html for more details.