# Response time in Axios Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using the following snippet to hit an API and get its response. **I want to know how much time it took to fetch the data**

```
const fetch_table_data = async () => { const response = await axios.get(`URL_HERE`, {headers : {'Authorization': 'Token abc'}});if (response.status === 200){
      // what is the time taken to fetch this data??? <-------------------
    }}
    fetch_table_data()
```

Please suggest a workaround. Thanks

Comment: Its answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874594/how-to-get-response-times-from-axios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the native [Performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) interface.

```
const fetch_table_data = async () => {
    const request_start_at = performance.now();

    const response = await axios.get(`URL_HERE`, {
        headers : {
            'Authorization': 'Token abc'
        }
    });

    const request_end_at = performance.now();
    const request_duration = request_ent_at - request_start_at;

    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log(duration);
    }
} 

fetch_table_data()
```