# Make sure Axios/Fetch call runs for at least X Seconds in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

odd question. if I wanted to make sure that my query ran for at least X seconds (e.g. 1sec), how would you tackle that? I have React Query that looks like this, but really just need the axios call to have some kind of time tracker on it.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { themeKeys } from './themeKeys';
import { webApiBaseUrl, config } from "../apiConstants";

export const fetchTheme = (themeId) =>
    axios.get(`${webApiBaseUrl}/themes/${themeId}`, config)
        .then((res) => res.data);

export default function useTheme(themeId) {
    return useQuery(
        themeKeys.theme(themeId), 
        () => fetchTheme(themeId),
        {
            failureCount: 3,
            retryOnMount: false,
            refetchOnMount: false,
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            refetchOnReconnect: false,
            cacheTime: Infinity,
            staleTime: Infinity
        }
    );
}
```

I have something like this adding a delay, but not sure how to track how long the axios call ran for to deduct from the `wait`

```
export const fetchTheme = async (themeId) => {
    return axios.get(`${webApiBaseUrl}/themes/${themeId}`, config)
        .then((res) => res.data)
        .then( await wait(750));
};

function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise( (resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
```

Comment: This answer might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51279029/3999660

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put both of your promises inside [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). That way if `fetch` finished first `Promise.all` will wait for `wait` to finish.

```js
await Promise.all([fetchTheme(themeId), wait(750)])
```

Comment: I like this, but need to return the response from `fetchTheme` for this to work. what does promise all return?

Comment: const [result, _] = await Promise.all([fetch(), wait()]) it returns an array of resolved results